# Possible to disable/hide one of two scanner options in XSane?

Tags: scanner, canon, 21.10

After struggling for some time, I've finally got my Canon LiDE 400 scanner working on Ubuntu 21.10, but now I have sort of the opposite problem. When I start up XSane, it makes me choose between 2 scanners when I only have 1.

scanimage -L gives the same "2" scanners and is easier to copy and paste, so I'll show that output:

```
device `escl:http://localhost:60000' is a Canon LiDE 400 (USB) platen scanner
device `airscan:e0:Canon LiDE 400 (USB)' is a eSCL Canon LiDE 400 (USB) ip=127.0.0.1
```

I've tested both and they both seem to work fine, I would just like to not have to choose when I only, in fact, have 1 scanner.

Please let me know what additional information I can provide, and if there is any reason to prefer one of these options over the other.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first device in the list is provided by `libsane`, which cannot be removed without destroying all scanning. `sane-airscan` is an independently produced backend.

Therefore, the definitive answer is:

`sudo apt purge sane-airscan`

Happy?

Comment: Ending your message with "Happy?" suggests that I have burdened you in some way, which seems unwarranted. At the risk of further irritating you, can I ask you to explain why you've suggested I remove that package, particularly?

Comment: You are misinterpreting. I cannot recollect feeling burdened or irritated at the time. In fact, I thought it an interesting situation. The first device is provided by libsane, which cannot be removed without destroying all scanning. sane-airscan is an independently produced backend.

Comment: Thanks! I'll give it a try and report back.

Comment: After a little hardware-related hiccup, things now work the way I wanted them to. Thanks to @brian_p for the help!